# PyCharm having trouble with inferring ndb property type

Tags: python, intellij-idea, google-app-engine, pycharm

While developing a Google AppEngine application with PyCharm, I am constantly seeing an issue where PyCharm doesn't properly infer the ndb property type.

What is the best way to work around this issue?

*Here is an example where it shows the `self.host_key.get()` as an unresolved error, because it thinks it's of type `KeyProperty`, but it isn't*

[image]